# Android Button text not centered when using API 17 for rendering

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

In the graphical view of layout, when I choose API 15 or lower from the button shown in the image below, the text in the encircled buttons looks fine.

[image]

When I choose API 17, the text is displaced even though the xml code is same. Changing the button padding does not help.

[image]

Is this just a problem with Eclipse or is it possible that new versions of android may see this displaced text?

What's the workaround to fix this?

XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="3dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/label" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/about_title"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/temp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/news" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/tournaments" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/results" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`android:gravity="center"` did not help

I restarted eclipse twice. Strangely it did not help in the first restart but it looked fine after the second one. Also, its working fine on device.
Apologies for the question, I must have waited before posting the question.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if the default style for Buttons changed in API17... possibly...

Anyway, adding `android:gravity="center"` should be fixing this for you.

Answer (score 2):

i don't know i faced this problem check restart a eclipse.. and check..

Answer (score 0):

adding `android:gravity="center"` should be fixing this for you