# How do I center text in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, text, center

I've read all the possible solutions, but still can't fix this:

This is my code:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/your_total"
    android:textSize="45sp" />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

I want the text to be centered, but it only **starts from the center** - [you can see it here](http://s11.postimg.org/sb4al1537/stack.png), both in textView and the button.
Thank you!

Comment: android:layout_gravity="fill" is incorrect. Try center, or android:gravity="center" on the button.

Comment: that code does not compile. also, are you certain of the content of your string ?

Comment: the string is fine, and I can see the full string when the text is aligned to left.
Also, changed the "fill" into "center" but nothing has changed...

Comment: What do your `String` `xml` lines look like?
Example:
`<string name="date">Date</string>`

Comment: <string name="your_total">Your total is 0</string>

Comment: what's the layout u're using as parent and respective parameters?

Comment: both width and height are `match_parent`.

Comment: pls share your full xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:text="@string/your_total"
android:textSize="45sp" />
```

Instead of

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/your_total"
android:textSize="45sp" />
```

Comment: I've tried this... it looks like this: [link] (http://s27.postimg.org/dcubvj18z/Capture.png)

Answer (score 0):

i've tested your textview inside a `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`, and the text is centered:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MENSAGEM DE TESTE"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```

I'll assume your problem is the main layout, specifically your **`android:layout_width`** should be `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help, the answer was finally found in [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586521/android-button-text-not-centered-when-using-api-17-for-rendering): Restart Eclipse.
I think it's somehow connected to the API version (I use 20).